# remove rows of a table except the first 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i do that?

thanks

Comment: Yuo will have to be a little more specific than that.

Comment: Lucca, What kind of Table? HTML/SQL/...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple with a standard for loop:

```
int rowCount = myTable.Rows.Count;
for(int i = 2; i < rowCount; i++) {
    myTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```